# How to load Panel in TabPanel after click Tab extjs?

Tags: ext.net

When page load, all Panel in TabPanel autoload. I don't want it. How to load Panel after click to this Tab?

```
           <ext:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlQLDB" Border="false" Layout="fit">
                <Items>
                    <ext:TabPanel ID="TabDB" Border="false" runat="server">
                        <Items>

                            <ext:Panel ID="panTest" Border="false" runat="server">
                                <Content>
                                    <uc:NHQH ID="NHQH" runat="server" />
                                </Content>
                            </ext:Panel>
                            <ext:Panel ID="panTest1" Border="false" runat="server">
                                <Content>
                                    <uc:NSQHCLY ID="NSQHCLY" runat="server" />
                                </Content>
                            </ext:Panel>
                            <ext:Panel ID="panTest2" Border="false" runat="server">
                                <Content>
                                    <uc:NSQTLS ID="NSQTLS" runat="server" />
                                </Content>
                            </ext:Panel>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:TabPanel>
                </Items>
            </ext:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can write `load` functionality on `activate` event of `Ext.tab.Panel` or `Ext.tab.Tab`.